# Keep focus on EditText after opening popup window?

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I'm not sure if this is possible but I have an EditText that I'm using as a search box. When the user touches the box a ListPopUpWindow widget is created and shows a list of search results, filtering them as the user types. The problem is when the list pops up it takes away control from the edit text so after typing one letter, they lose control until the popup closes.

I've tried calling requestfocus() on the EditText imediately, but it doesn't work. Here's my code:

```
public class SearchablePopupList {

EditText anchorView;    //The view that the pop up list will be attached to
Activity activity;
private ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;
private ArrayList<String> filterList;

public SearchablePopupList(final EditText anchorView, Activity activity, final ArrayList<String> filterList){

    this.anchorView = anchorView;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.filterList = filterList;


     listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(activity);

      ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, 
               android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, filterList);

     listPopupWindow.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(anchorView);


            listPopupWindow.setHeight(600);
            listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
            listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                     anchorView.setText(filterList.get(position));
                        listPopupWindow.dismiss();

                }});


            anchorView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {
                    listPopupWindow.show();
                    anchorView.requestFocus();

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }});                

}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried setting Modal to false?

Comment: That did the trick! I had forgotten I pasted that in there from the tuorial I was following. thanks!