# AlertDialog on top of EditText Layout, Not showing the Keyboard

Tags: android

I have a layout which contains an EditText input field and on top of this layout i'm popping up an AlertDialog(Advertisement). The problem is that SoftKeyBoard is not popping up when click on the EditText. Is there any work around to achieve this requirement?

[image]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_secondary"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="inova.lk.com.librarytestapp.main.SecondaryActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:hint="Enter Name"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

AlertDialog:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   dialog.setContentView(inova.lk.com.inapplibrary.R.layout.custom_dialog_layout);
dialog.setCancelable(false);

Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
);

window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
wmlp.width = Utility.dpToPx(320);
wmlp.height = Utility.dpToPx(50);

dialog.show();
```

UPDATE*****

I'm developing an advertisement SDK like google adz. AlertDialog is my adz banner. Banner on top of edittext layout is one scenario. Therefore I want a solution that will not require users who use my SDK to do any changes by their side.

Comment: remove this line from your xml " android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
"

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455235/when-using-alertdialog-builder-with-edittext-the-soft-keyboard-doesnt-pop

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Please read the question. Here I'm talking about a different scenario. That question you pointed out is talking about what happens when the EditText contains inside of the AlertDialog.

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari I tried that and still not working. Thanks

Comment: @MilanJayawardane *Not the Downvoter* for duplicate..just a suggestion to check...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 i don't care about votes. I'm just looking for a solution. I spend lots of time on this matter and still i couldn't figure out a work around to handle this. Thanks

Comment: call `clearFocus()` on your advertisement dialog..it may blocks the keyboard

Comment: I don't know why people are down voting this question instead of sharing their knowledge on this matter :(

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 From where should I call this method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put these lines before dialog.show();

```
try{ 
      dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
   }catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Comment: This works if the EditText contain inside of the AlertDialog. Thanks

Comment: I'm developing an advertisement SDK like google adz. AlertDialog is my adz banner. Banner on top of edittext layout is one scenario. Therefore I want a solution that will not require users to do any changes by their side. Thanks

Comment: so you want to show keyboard when your alert dialog ads load in screen?

Comment: Actually this is a one scenario. If a developer use my SDK to show a top banner in his page which contains EditText input fields then he can't interact with those input fields(SoftKeyBoard is not popping up) until he close the banner. But onclick, scroll like function are working without any problem.

Comment: It's similar to this problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331247/keep-focus-on-edittext-after-opening-popup-window

Comment: As I mentioned before, here they are talking about a different issue. It's a scenario where EditText is in the PopUp Dialog. In my case popup dialog doesn't have any input field but popup dialog is popping up on a layout which contain a input field. Thanks

Comment: above link does not allow to get focus in dialog. so your edittext remain focused after popup dialog

Answer (score 0):

> i'm popping up an AlertDialog(Advertisement).

Why you have to use an AlertDialog? Since your Advertisement is placed on top of the layout always, you may not need an AlertDialog, instead just use a FrameLayout and place it above the top of your layout.

Comment: I'm developing a SDK and there are adz types (like google adz). For example top banner, bottom banner, full screen banner, etc. if I provide a custom view then developers can place that view anywhere in the layout. So that i won't be able to force developers to put top banners, bottom banners, etc.